# jScrollPane - scrollToBottom when reinitialise

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I am using [jScrollPane Plugin](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) for Scrolling a `div`.

My content is dynamic so I use `autoReinitialise: true` in plugin as

```
var scrollPane = $('element').jScrollPane({
    autoReinitialise: true,
    verticalGutter: 0
});
```

I want that my content pane should be `scrolllToBottom` when it `reinitialise`.

Is there any event or anything else which solve my issue?

Comment: Don't; all browsers natively support scrolling (except Android 2.3, but still, don't.)

Comment: I am using this plugin for better css.

Comment: To make custom, non-standard scrollbars. That's precisely what I'm telling you not to do. It's just not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to the [`jsp-initialised`](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/events.html) event (which is called on re-initializing), and call the [`scrollToBottom`](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html#scrollToBottom) API method on the element that fired the event.

### Example:

```
var scrollPane = $('element').jScrollPane({
    autoReinitialise: true,
    verticalGutter: 0
});

scrollPane.on('jsp-initialised', function() {
    $(this).data('jsp').scrollToBottom();
});
```